# Trying to make jquery validation errors get added dynamically, why isn't this code working?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I'm using the following code to try and dynamically add the error labels and not have to use so many if else statements but it doesn't seem to work, any help appreciated :)

This works:

```
errorPlacement: function(error, element) {

        if (element.attr("name") == "site" )
            error.insertAfter("div#siteerror");
        else if  (element.attr("name") == "name" )
            error.insertAfter("div#nameerror");
        else if  (element.attr("name") == "email" )
            error.insertAfter("div#emailerror");
        else if  (element.attr("name") == "password" )
            error.insertAfter("div#passworderror");
        else if  (element.attr("name") == "headerimage" )
            error.insertAfter("div#headerimageerror");
        else if  (element.attr("name") == "header1" )
            error.insertAfter("div#header1error");
        else if  (element.attr("name") == "header2" )
            error.insertAfter("div#header2error");
        else if  (element.attr("name") == "headerfont" )
            error.insertAfter("div#headerfonterror");
        else if  (element.attr("name") == "menucolor" )
            error.insertAfter("div#menucolorerror");
        else if  (element.attr("name") == "menufontcolor" )
            error.insertAfter("div#menufontcolorerror");
        else if  (element.attr("name") == "menufont" )
            error.insertAfter("div#menufonterror");
        else if  (element.attr("name") == "backgroundcolor" )
            error.insertAfter("div#backgroundcolorerror");
        else if  (element.attr("name") == "sitefontcolor" )
            error.insertAfter("div#sitefontcolorerror");
        else if  (element.attr("name") == "sitefont" )
            error.insertAfter("div#sitefonterror");
        else if  (element.attr("name") == "galleryimages" )
            error.insertAfter("div#galleryimageserror");
        else
            error.insertAfter(element);
    },
```

but this doesn't:

```
errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
var $inputs = $('input');
$inputs.each(function(){
    var name = $(this).attr('name');
    var errorname = ('"div#' + name + 'error"')
if (name === name) {
    console.log("name: " + name + " " + "errorname: " + errorname);
    error.insertAfter($($.parseHTML(errorname)));
    console.log("name matches!");
} else {
    error.insertAfter(element);
}
});
},
```

it returns all of the correct values but for some reason just won't work, any ideas?

Comment: what is this supposed to do? `if (name === name)`

Comment: make sure the element matches itself, i know it's kind of pointless i suppose but i just need it to return true and insert the error name after each input and get the matching attribute then pass it into the error name by matching the div id which also is the same as the name so i use the name variable to get the attr for the id as well, my console logs return all of the correct variables i need but it just won't work..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The developer has given you the `element` argument which represents the element being validated.

```
var name = $(element).attr('name');
```

Since `errorPlacement` deals with each element as it's being validated, you do not need the `.each()` loop, and the `element` argument will work for each one already.

You messed up your quotation marks here, missed a semicolon, and you don't need the parenthesis...

```
var errorname = ('"div#' + name + 'error"')
```

This works instead...

```
var errorname = 'div#' + name + 'error';
```

If you're trying to insert the error message into a specific `div`...

```
$(errorname).html(error);
```

`if (name === name)` is also totally pointless, because there will never be a scenario where it's not equal to itself.

**DEMO:  [jsfiddle.net/rttLsoxL/](http://jsfiddle.net/rttLsoxL/)**

Final:

```
errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
    var name = $(element).attr('name');
    var errorname = 'div#' + name + 'error';
    console.log("name: " + name + " " + "errorname: " + errorname);
    $(errorname).html(error);
},
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the insightful explanations as well as the solution, this really helped me analyze some of my flawed logic and improve my thought process in approaching the initiual situation, I great appreciate your help and hope you have a wonderful day!